# In the .net Graph SDK, Range().Clear() gives compilation error and doesn't work as told in documentation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-excel

I am using .net Graph SDK (Microsoft.Graph) version 3.21. I am following the below documentation link from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-clear?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp
In this link, it is said that we can clear a range of cells and C# code to do so is given. When I try, I am getting error for the Clear
[I am able to get Range, but the clear shows error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJxTw.png)
Error   CS1061  'IWorkbookWorksheetRangeRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no accessible extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type 'IWorkbookWorksheetRangeRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something? What else am I supposed to do?

Note:
All other Graph calls work. I am able to retrieve Range:
var range = await _graphServiceClient.Sites["root"].Drives[file.ParentReference.DriveId]
.Items[file.Id].Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Range().Request().GetAsync();

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bug, not only Clear but also Delete/Format/Merge... are not contained. There is a similar [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/490). The methods work in Java but not C#, Filipowicz251 has commented [it](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/233#issuecomment-718204927) in Github.

You could call HTTP Request to clear range values without sdk.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/names/{name}/range/clear
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 32

{
  "applyTo": "applyTo-value"
}
```

Example here: https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/01/31/using-microsoft-graph-api-to-interact-with-azure-ad/